# tortoise svn client head revision is different from server svn repository head revision

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Facing issue while importing(checkout) svn repository to my local working copy through tortoise svn, i am unable to cleanup and import entire repository from svn server due to cache files name contain special characters.

In order to solve above issue methods i followed are listed below.

Method 1] Cleared saved data, clear log cache from svn settings.

Method 2] In order to do svn cleanup i fallowed below blog, as per instruction i deleted the work_queue then i can able to do svn cleanup, but still i am unable to checkout the entire source code, later through tortoise svn i deleted cache files from the repository and committed and then whole repository i can able to checkout from the repository but revision number stick to 7, actual head revision number in server is 1409. logs available until 7 revision.
http://www.anujvarma.com/svn-cleanup-failedprevious-operation-has-not-finished-run-cleanup-if-it-was-interrupted/

Method 3] Entirely deleted project root folder on svn client machine & tried to do svn checkout but  still revision number 7 files only coming.

Method 4] Uninstalled tortoisesvn software and reinstalled and restarted the system then did svn checkout but still i am unable to get head revision data.

Method 5] Directly tried to checkout head revision(1409) number but -no such revision error is coming.

Method 6] Imported revision number 7 data to working copy and tried to update to head revision 1409 -no such revision error is coming

How to checkout to latest head revision?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this. Create a folder on your local machine somewhere and perform:

1. Right click folder, SVN Checkout...
2. Enter the URL of your Repo and path to your local folder
3. Where it says **Checkout Depth**, choose the option that says **Choose Items...** and then click the top level folder of whatever directory you're trying to checkout and make sure that every item in the repository is selected.
4. Click OK

See if every item checks out of the repo.

Comment: I tried as per u r instruction but still i am getting only revision number 7 files, svn repository head revision is 1409, if i directly access url of the repository in browser only revision 7 files only displaying, but if i access through other system i am getting revision 1409 files.